# 改行はそのまま改行として扱ってほしい

Tags: 討議, 完了, markdown

「改行には、半角スペースを2個追加します」というルールはちょっと欧米的なルールな気がします。

半角スペースを入れなくても改行がそのまま br タグに置き換わる方が、日本人が文章を入力する場合に自然な気がするのですがどうでしょうか？（「うん、そうだ」「いや、そうじゃない」と意見が分かれそうですが・・・）

個人的にはQiitaのMarkdownは日本人として自然に文章が打てる気がします。

Comment: QiitaのMarkdownは[こちら](https://github.com/increments/qiita-markdown)ですか？改行以外に、他の差はありますか？（特に絵文字は入らないと思いますが、他は適用可能かどうかを検討します）

Comment: 「欧米的」という点を理解したいのですが、 1.「欧米の段組では改行するのに半角スペースを2個入れるのが普通だが、和文では改行がそのまま反映されるのが普通だ」ということですか? 2. それとも「和文では改行を多用するので、"半角スペースを入れないと改行されない"という例外的なルールより、改行がそのまま反映される方が書きやすい」ということですか?

Comment: すいません、たしかに「欧米的」という表現は何を意味しているのかわかりにくいですね。

僕が言いたかったのは日本語と英語で段落の区切り方が異なる、ということでした。

- 日本語 = 改行して先頭を一字空ける
- 英語 = 空行を入れる（先頭は一字空けない）

英語の文章のサンプルはたとえばこんな感じです。

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s302/sh/87d13674-217e-4ec3-8439-7326207a95ca/602441d9338453b25b56f17df56e7739

http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/12/23/how-to-choose-from-conflicting-rails-advice/

こういう文法的な違いから、改行を二つ入れると段落が切り替わる、という仕様は英語を書く人にとっては自然だけど、日本人はそうじゃなく、改行一つで素直に改行してほしいと感じるはず、と僕個人は考えています。

（文字だけだとこのニュアンスを伝えるのが結構難しい・・・）

Comment: もう少し補足します。（勝手な想像ですが）英語ネイティブから見ると、「空行を入れずに改行する」という仕様は重要性が低いのではないかと思っています。なので、「半角スペースを2つ入れる」という不便な仕様になっているんじゃないかと思います。しかし、日本人は「空行を入れずに改行する」というニーズは高い（はず）なので、スペース2つなんて入れなくても改行したらいいのに、と思っています。
で、僕はこう思ってるんですが、みなさん、どう思われますか？不便さを感じませんか？というのが冒頭の質問の意図です。

Comment: 開発者が検討していますが、サイト毎に異なるMarkdownを使うことを実施する前、十分検討が必要です。年末でもあったので、しばらくお待ち下さい。改行ぐらいは優先度高くつけています。

Comment: 「英文は空行を入れてインデントしない」というのは必ずしも正しくなく、おそらくHTMLの仕様（行頭の半角スペースは無視される）に依るものであり、むしろ英語の文章でも日本と同じように段落はインデントすることが一般的ではないかと思います（[参考](http://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/texwiki/?%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E6%96%87%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%93%E8%A3%81#h6253c9c)）。空行に関しては何とも言えませんが、日本語でも、横書きのwebページでは１行が長くなる上に行間が詰まるので、ブログなどを見ても空行を開けている人が多いように思えます。

Comment: @JunichiIto 補足ありがとうございます。争点は「段落の中で改行を入れたら、改行として表示してほしい」だと思っていたのですが、「改行したら段落分けとして表示してほしい」ということですか? (補足の前半を読んで、そうなのかもと考えました)

Comment: 「段落の中で改行を入れたら、改行として表示してほしい」で合っています。（brタグが入るイメージ）

上の説明では段落の話をしましたが、実際のところ、SOに書き込むときは段落を分けたいから改行を入れるのではなく、「画面で読みやすくするため」に改行を入れることが多いと思います。
なので、あまり「改行 = 段落かどうか」にはこだわらなくてもよいと思います。

Comment: ちなみに記事のdiffの話がたくさん出てきていますが、そこまで頻繁にdiffを見ないので、個人的には優先度が低いんですよね～。それよりも、書き込むときに思った通りに改行してくれる方がずっと嬉しいなあと思っています。（そんな話をしてたら宗教論争にしかなりませんが。。。）

Comment: @JunichiIto 改行を[Shift+Enter]にすればどうですか？ワード等と同じ改行入力方法ですし、従来のMarkdownも壊れないようになります。それでも不便でしょうか？（現在[この回答](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1600/10)のコメントで話し合い中です）

Comment: @jmac うーん、悪くはないですが、初めて使う人にとってもわかりやすい（もしくは気付きやすい）かというと微妙ですね。。。そもそも、改行の件に関しては僕と同じように考えている人も多いんじゃないかな？と思って書き込んでみたんですが、予想に反して結構炎上（？）してしまったので、ちょっとびっくりしています。あまり賛同が得られないなら、以前の仕様に戻してもらっても構いません。Markdownには方言がいろいろあるので、改行の扱いもどれか一つを「正しい」と決められないと思うので。

Answer (score 11):

私は今の状態で良いと考えています。

あくまでも主観にとどまりますが、
編集時のdiffが行単位で出力されるので、
意味の区切りで積極的に改行を挟んだほうが、
編集の過程・内容をトレースしやすいのです
(この文章自体も、積極的に改行を入れています)。
しかし、その物理的な改行通りに表示上も改行されちゃうと、
段落の概念が崩れて日本語…というか文としては不自然になります。

あと経験上、markdownの解釈に変更が発生すると
既存の質問&回答のマイグレーションがかなり大変ですよ。

---

**追記**

もうちょっと客観的な意見を思いついたので追記します。

編集可能な **参考資料** としては、
その編集内容のトレースの容易性も考慮したほうが良いです。
qiitaは他人が記事を編集することはできませんが(できないですよね?)、
SOはできてしまいます。
だからmarkdownの解釈方法という1機能の比較だけで済ますのは、適切ではないかもしれません。

Comment: まぁ、あくまでも参考までということでw

Comment: 私も個人的にですが今のままで良いと思います。どこまで揃えるかという問題も出てくると思います（コードブロックもGithub Flavorなフェンスはありませんし）。慣れてるスタイルでかけた方が楽なのはそうなんですけどね。私もQA@ITとの違いに気をつけながらもたまにバッククォート三連打ったりしてます。  
Markdown自体いろいろ派生があるのでどこに寄せるといいかという問題もありますし、Commonmarkの方が固まってきて標準らしくなってきたのならそれにマイグレートするとか選択できるようになるなどしても良いと思いますが、現状では今のままでも良いかなと思います。

Comment: もっと討議できるように、[新しい質問を作成しました](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1587/%E6%94%B9%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8B)。興味があれば、是非そこで投稿してください。

Comment: 話はそれますが、Qiitaも他人が編集できる機能があります。「編集リクエスト」と言い、最初の投稿者に承認を求める点がスタックオーバーフローと異なりますが。

Answer (score 4):

もし「幅いっぱいで書くと読みにくいので、改行を積極的に入れたい」というニーズであれば、「幅いっぱいで書いても読みやすくする」のがStackExchange側としては望ましい対応だと思います。

(20-30文字くらいで`<br/>`を入れている投稿が複数あったので、そういうニーズなのかなと推測しました。)

というのも、「読みやすい幅」はデスクトップ版かモバイル版かなど表示方法に依存するパラメータなので、投稿データとしては見た目ではなく文章の意味を基準とした改行がされている方が望ましいためです。

Answer (score 3):

とりあえず、改行が半角スペースなしで行えるようになりました。
他のMarkdownに関しての要求があれば、別の質問でご教示ください。

Comment: [meta-tag:status-deferred]になった日に票が増えて、質問のスコア: +8、「今のままでよい」という回答のスコア: +7 になったので、賛成と反対が拮抗しているのかなと思っていました。とはいえ、扱いをまた元に戻すこともできると思うので、しばらくこれで使い勝手をみるというのもよいかと思います。

Comment: @ento 考えとしては「このままでいい」といった人に対しても、この変化は悪影響がないと想定しました。逆に、変更しないと改行をよく使う人に対してまだ不満が残るため、変えた方がベストだと思いました。この変更で非常に不満が出てこないなら、このままで残すつもりです。

Comment: > この変化は悪影響がないと想定: 「このままでいい」人の中には、[KoRoNさんの投稿](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/1517/edit)のように、表示上は改行せずにテキスト上で改行したい (ハードラップしたい) という人もいると思います。そういう人には影響が出る (ハードラップする方法が無くなる) 変更になりますね。そういうニーズがある人の割合が分かりませんが。

Comment: @ento 多分勘違いですが、それは日本語での編集「diff」がうまくいっていないからだと思います。その問題を直せば、KoRoNさんの疑問も無くすことができると思います。

Comment: [diffが単語単位でハイライトされない](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1453/30)問題ですよね。それが解決しても、diffが行単位であることには変わりがないので、おそらく同じニーズは残ると思います。(細かく改行を入れた方が、変更箇所をピンポイントしやすいので。) また、diff以外の理由でハードラップしたい場合もあるかもしれません。

Comment: @ento 多分この変更のデメリットを正しく理解できていないと思います。自分が理解している範囲で、9割以上の疑問がdiffの改善でなくなるし、残りはコーナーケースだと思います。もし具体的に説明してくれたら（他の回答でとか）、それをレビューします。

Comment: @jmac 記事を編集していて、改行の扱いの変更があったことに気づきましたがちょっと慣れないです。外部エディタが適用できなくなりましたし、また現在の自分にはとても違和感があります。まあ、そのうち慣れると思いますが。。。「スタックオーバーフロー日本版の独自フォーマット」と、「Markdownフォーマット」を選べるようにはできませんでしょうか。

Comment: @jmac http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1569/30 にまとめを投稿しました。インラインdiffだと行単位の表示ではないので、改行を細かく入れる効果はないですね。いつも「左右2列markdown」で見ていたので気付きませんでした。

Comment: @jmac ありがとうございます！僕としては大変嬉しいです。Markdownにそれほど精通していない技術者にとっても、きっと助かる仕様変更だと思います。

Comment: 正直、私はとても使いにくいと、感じています。

@HiroshiYamamoto さんの言うように選べるとありがたいです。

Comment: SOに参加したての立場から述べさせていただきます。
改行で改行が反映されるのはとても自然で、書きやすいです。

Comment: @jmac 慣れる慣れないの問題以前に、この変更の影響で、以前に比べて、質問の品質が相当下がった気がします。ひとつひとつ直していましたが、質問が多くなれば収集がつかなくなります。・・・この改行の扱いの変更は、決定なんですか？ StackOverflow 的に質問の質を下げるのは良くないことだと思いますが。。。

Comment: @ento もっと討議できるように、[新しい質問を作成しました](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1587/%E6%94%B9%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8B)。興味があれば、是非そこで投稿してください。

Answer (score 3):

論点を整理します。コミュニティWiki化してあるので、追記・修正があればお願いします。

### 争点

段落の中で強制的に改行を入れたい時、どういう記法が最適なのか?

### 用語の定義

**強制改行**: 表示する時にブラウザに強制的に改行を入れさせるようなマークアップ (通常の改行もマークアップとみなす)

**非強制改行**: 表示する時にブラウザに改行を強制しないが、Markdownテキスト上では改行するようなマークアップ

**ママ改行モード**: 強制改行を多用する場合に書きやすいマークアップモード

- 強制改行するには: 改行する
- 非強制改行するには: 非強制改行はできない
- 段落を分けるには: 改行を2個入れる

<sup>「ママ」は mom ではなく「そのまま」の「儘」のことです。</sup>

**特殊改行モード**: 非強制改行を多用する場合に書きやすいマークアップモード (元来のMarkdown)

- 強制改行するには: 行の末尾に空白を 2 個入れる
- 非強制改行するには: 改行する
- 段落を分けるには: 改行を2個入れる

#### 各種執筆・表示スタイル

**文の途中で積極的に強制改行する (文中改行スタイル)**

吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。

どこで生れたかとんと見当がつかぬ。
何でも薄暗いじめじめした所で
ニャーニャー泣いていた事だけは記憶している。
吾輩はここで始めて人間というものを見た。
しかもあとで聞くとそれは書生という
人間中で一番獰悪な種族であったそうだ。
この書生というのは時々
我々を捕えて煮て食うという話である。
しかしその当時は何という考もなかったから
別段恐しいとも思わなかった。
ただ彼の掌に載せられてスーと持ち上げられた時
何だかフワフワした感じがあったばかりである。

**文単位で強制改行する (文単位改行スタイル)**

吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。

どこで生れたかとんと見当がつかぬ。何でも薄暗いじめじめした所でニャーニャー泣いていた事だけは記憶している。吾輩はここで始めて人間というものを見た。
しかもあとで聞くとそれは書生という人間中で一番獰悪な種族であったそうだ。この書生というのは時々我々を捕えて煮て食うという話である。
しかしその当時は何という考もなかったから別段恐しいとも思わなかった。ただ彼の掌に載せられてスーと持ち上げられた時何だかフワフワした感じがあったばかりである。

**強制改行を使わない (段落オンリースタイル)**

吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。

どこで生れたかとんと見当がつかぬ。何でも薄暗いじめじめした所でニャーニャー泣いていた事だけは記憶している。吾輩はここで始めて人間というものを見た。しかもあとで聞くとそれは書生という人間中で一番獰悪な種族であったそうだ。この書生というのは時々我々を捕えて煮て食うという話である。しかしその当時は何という考もなかったから別段恐しいとも思わなかった。ただ彼の掌に載せられてスーと持ち上げられた時何だかフワフワした感じがあったばかりである。

### 論点

#### 日本語ではどの執筆・表示スタイルが一般的なのか?

「文中改行スタイル」や「文単位改行スタイル」が一般的な場合: → ママ改行モードが最適

「段落オンリースタイル」が一般的な場合: → 特殊改行モード、またはどちらでもよい

#### 編集する時に最適な改行スタイルと、読む時に最適な改行スタイルは違うのか?

違いは**ない**と考える場合: → ママ改行モードが最適

- 編集時: いずれかの改行スタイル
- 表示時: 編集時の改行スタイルでそのまま表示する

違いは**ある**と考える場合: → 特殊改行モードが最適

- 編集時: 文中改行スタイルや文単位改行スタイル
- 表示時: 段落オンリースタイル
- 根拠: 編集内容を確認する時、積極的に改行を入れておくと、「左右2列 markdown」のdiffで差分の範囲が限定されてみやすい。

  積極的に改行を入れた場合の例:

  [image: 行単位]

  改行を入れない場合の例:

  [image: 段落単位]

#### テキストの横幅に応じた改行箇所を、表示するソフトウェア側で自動調整すべきか?

自動調整する**べきでない**と考える場合: → ママ改行モードが最適

- 根拠: 書く人が、読みやすいところで改行するのだから、ソフトウェア側で調整すべきではない

自動調整する**べき**と考える場合: → 特殊改行モードが最適

- 根拠: 書く人が、読みやすいところで改行するとは限らないので、読みにくい投稿文をたやすく書けてしまわないように自動調整するべき

  - 例: [文中改行スタイル](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/4308/30)が最近[散見](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/4317/30)されるが、読みにくい (読みにくいかは意見が分かれる?)
  - 反論: 読みにくければ編集で対応すればよい
- 根拠: 表示するコンテキスト (デスクトップ / モバイル) によって最適な幅が違うので、表示するソフトウェア側で調整した方が読みやすくなる

#### 一般的なMarkdownの実装と改行スタイルを合わせた方がよいか?

**合わせる**のがよいと考える場合: → 特殊改行モードが最適

- 根拠: 外部エディタで投稿を準備しやすい

**合わせなくてよい**と考える場合: → どちらでもよい

- 根拠: 日本語版SOでの使いやすさを優先すべき

### 参考資料

- [meta.se: Markdownでなぜ非強制改行がデフォルトなのかの説明](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45635/157841) (テキストメールの扱いを踏襲した: 段落分けは空白行であらわし、改行する幅はメーラー側で自動調整する)

Answer (score 2):

私からも参考程度に……

まずQiitaには**編集リクエスト**というPullReqのような機能があります。SOのユーザー編集とは『**誰**が承認するか』が違うかもしれませんが同様の機能だと思っています。(QiitaがSOを参考にして作られたこともあるかと思いますが……)
ところでdiffはSOでは単語区切りで文字数の増減も比較出来ますよね(現状日本語でスペース区切りでは問題ありと別トピックに上がってたと思いますが)。Wikipediaにも同様の機能があったかと思いますがその辺りを考えるとdiffのために改行を多用する必要は無いようにも感じます。編集時の見易さを考えると現状のスペース2つでいいかと思いますが。
ちなみにQiitaのdiffは文字、単語単位での表示には**対応しておらず**行単位です。細かい編集が多いエントリーは編集履歴で差分を探すのに苦労することが希にあります。

またこれもSOを使う上ではあまり関係無いかもしれないのですが多くのMarkdownエディタは基本仕様又は一般的な拡張に対応していますが改行(`<br>`)はスペース2つです。もちろんGitHubのMarkdownだってそうです。
この辺りになると慣れの問題も含むのかもしれませんか……一般的な(本来の)[Markdownの仕様](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p)なので……(Qiitaが日本人に使いやすく拡張しているという考えはその通りかと思いますが。)

---

ちなみに私は3連バッククオートのpreブロックが使いたいです。

Comment: 「3連バッククオートのpreブロック」に +1 ですが、それは別に建てた良い気がしますねw