# 改行はどうするべきか？

Tags: 討議, markdown

Markdown（当サイトが使っている書式）では、<kbd>Return</kbd>を押すと改行が出ません。行の最後に「  」（半角スペース2つ）を入れないと1行の改行になりません。

[前に機能要求がありまして](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513/%E6%94%B9%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BE%E3%81%BE%E6%94%B9%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%89%B1%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%84)「半角スペースを入れなくても改行がそのまま br タグに置き換わる方が、日本人が文章を入力する場合に自然」。

ご存知かもしれませんが、英語では改行は段落の間にしかあまり使いませんが、日本語では改行をよく使われます。行を右に揃えたい場合、リストを作成したい場合などによく使うため、従来のMarkdownで不自然になります。

下記を投稿すれば：

```
古池や
蛙飛び込む
水の音
```

このように出力させます：

> 古池や蛙飛び込む水の音

そのために、勝手に改行を有効にしました（スペース二つを入れずにも）。

主な目的は3つでした：

#### 日本語のMarkdownニーズが英語と異なる

英語に1行の改行を稀にしか使わないため、Markdownであまり使わない機能ですが、日本語になると改行が多いため、ニーズが異なります。

#### Markdownを知らない人でも、書式をできるように

Markdownを知らない日本人は多いと思います。新ユーザーが書式と戦うとあまりいい印象が残らないし、気づかない人も多いため、投稿の書式が悪化する恐れがあります。

#### 日本語入力中で半角スペースが非常に不便

日本語で入力している時、半角スペースは特に入れにくいです（日本語を入力時、スペースが全角になるので、日本語入力中でスペースを入れても、改行になりません）

---

上記を考えた上で、改行の扱いのもっといい方法はありますか？

Answer (score 9):

> 日本語のMarkdownニーズが英語と異なる

「日本語になると改行が多い」は誤りです。日本語においても通常の作文においては、改行をそのように含めたりはしません。改行を大量に使用するのは、少し前に流行った「侍魂」のような「テキストサイト」に見られる特徴です。

なお挙げられている俳句の例は、通常の日本語の利用としては特殊すぎます。そのような詩や文学作品については、英語であろうとも改行が維持されるべきでしょう。

> Markdownを知らない人でも、書式をできるように

この目的は WYSIWYG なエディタを導入しないかぎり達成できません。私がこれまでに修正・編集してきた内容を考えると、そのような改行でスタイリングするべき場所は非常に少なく、むしろコードハイライトやリストを正しく使えていないケースのほうが遥かに多いです。

> 日本語入力中で半角スペースが非常に不便

ご利用になられている IME の設定の問題であって、日本語の問題ではありません。

百歩譲って改行をそのまま出力するのをデフォルトにするとしても、改行を残さないモードを選択できるようにできないでしょうか。というのは、改行を残さないことを前提とした過去の投稿を、今編集した場合、改行を全て修正しなければならないという事態に陥っています。

Comment: `「日本語になると改行が多い」は誤りです。`　とか　`ご利用になられている IME の設定の問題であって、日本語の問題ではありません。`　というより、データはありますか？事例証拠なら、僕も日本のオフィス10年間働いた経験では、英語より改行が多い、デフォルトなIMEを利用している人が多いと強調できます。環境によって、経験が全く異なるからこそ、事例証拠より、データの上で話しましょうか？

Comment: 事例証拠を認めて欲しいのではなく、日本語の定義に対する偏見を訂正して欲しいのです。

日本語で書かれた正式な文章、例えば技術書や論文をみても、段落などを除いた意味のない改行は避けられています(ライトノベルになると話は別ですがw)。これは日本における作文などの初等・中等教育でもそのような、改行を多く含む作文方法は推奨されていません。なので「日本語になると改行が多い」は、日本語に対する明らかな偏見です。

加えて、IMEの件はツールの設定次第でどうにでもなるので、変更する根拠としては弱いと言いたいのです。

Comment: あと本文中の改行の維持を認めるのであれば、コメント中の改行も認めて欲しいところです。今、長いのを書いて、非常にアンバランス&使いにくいと感じました。

Comment: 「作文スタイル」にこだわる必要はありますか？メインページを見るとスタイルは十人十色です。この変更で改行を使わないKoRoNさんに悪影響がないはずですが（改行を使わないから）、改行を使いたい人に向けてもっとサイトが使いやすくなったら、全体的に勝ちじゃないですか？（コメントは別物です。コメントは質問や回答より価値が低いため、改行を入れるとスペースをより多く取ってしまい、質問や回答からの強調が弱まってしまいます）

Comment: 「データの上で」というならば、あの「改行を維持するようにする」という変更自体も、voteなどのデータに基づいてなされるべきだったのではないでしょうか。少なくとも前のスレのvote 数を見る限りは、旧状維持の数のほうが多かったはずです。

Comment: 作文スタイルにこだわるのは「日本語には改行が多い」という偏見に基づく根拠を取り下げていただきたいからです。それこそ限られたサンプリングを元にした感想であって、事実とは異なります。

Comment: コメントの改行についての言い分はわからないでもないのですが、例えばjmacさんが最初に付けてくれたコメントなど、非常に意味がわかりにくいです。少なくとも私は、何が書いてあるのか理解するのに非常に時間がかかりました。これは単に改行だけではなく書式の問題ではありますが…しっかりなっていれば、もっと読みやすかったはず。

Comment: タグを[status-deferred]（実行したいと開発者に伝えた日）に質問8票、KoRoNさんの回答4票でした。変更をしてから8対8になりました。この変更は望ましくないと思っているのは理解しました。それだけで変更を戻すことはありません。KoRoNさんは改行していないと、この変更で問題がないはずです。他のユーザーが問題と思っているが、そのユーザーの声を無視した方がいいですか？

Comment: KoRoNさん、ご存知の通り、僕は日本人じゃないです。日本語の間違いも多いため、理解しづらいこともあると思います。それは書式の問題ではなく、それは弊職の日本語の問題です。最初のコメントのMarkdownがよくなかったのもありましたから、余計に読みづらくて、申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: ento さんからの「投稿データとしては見た目ではなく文章の意味を基準とした改行がされている方が望ましい」にも4票入っています。どちらに数えるか微妙なところですが、旧状維持と考えることもできます。

私としては、1.前の変更が客観的なデータ(もしくは何かしらのルール)に基づいていないことを認める、2.今後の同様の変更に対するポリシー&プロセスを明文化する、3.改行の処理方法の選択制の採用を**考慮**する、この3点が満たされれば満足です。特に3は本文にも「改行を残さないモードを選択できるように」と書いています。

Comment: あと「変更をしてから8対8になりました。」なんですが、これを私が確認する方法はあるでしょうか。vote の履歴を見る方法などがあったら、教えてください。

Comment: 変更のプロセスは簡単です。コミュニティの意見も聞くし、他言語版SOの経験者にも意見を聞きますが、あくまで自分の判断になります。今回の場合、8票対4票（投票の数やタイミングを見るのがモデレーターのみです）だったし、声を出さない過半数の人が8票の提案が有利と思いましたので、変更を実行しました。自分が誤った判断をすることもありますので、今回はこの投稿で反対意見のポイントを集めようとしました。この強い反対意見の元を理解した上で、変更を戻すか維持するかを判断します。何をしても、100％の人を100％満足させるのが不可能です。当サイトの目的を考えながら、ベストなバランスを探すしかありません。

Comment: 投票履歴は http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/1513/timeline?asc=True で確認できます。質問票 vs KoRoNさんの回答への票でいうと、8対4 → status-deferred / 8対7 → 変更 → 8対8 と遷移してます。

Answer (score 6):

改行に関してもう一つ考慮していただきたい事があります。それは、「（素の）Markdownでは改行は半角スペースに変換されるが、これは日本文には適さない」ということです。

英文の場合、基本的に行替えは単語の区切りでされるものであり、従ってエディタ内の改行は（直前がハイフン等の時を除いて）空白に置き換えるべきものです。しかし日本語の場合は単語の区切りに空白を置くということをしないので、エディタ内の改行は空白に置き換えずに単に無視するべきものです。以前の（素の）Markdown方式ではエディタ内で改行をすると文章中に無意味な空白が挿入されることになり、少し見づらくて気になっていました。

従って素のMarkdownに戻しても、このことを防ぐためにエディタ内で改行することが出来ないということに変わりはありません。日本文も適切に表示しようと思うと、Markdownを「**エディタ内で改行の前後の一方または両方が日本語の時は改行を無視し、それ以外の時は半角スペースに変換する**」という仕様に変更する必要があります。

個人的にはMarkdownのモドキが増えるのは嫌なので、できるだけ素のMarkdownのコンセプトに近い太字の仕様を採用してほしいです（というか本来Markdownはそういう仕様になるべきだったと思います）。しかしいずれにしても素のMarkdownに手を入れる必要があるのであれば、エディタ内の改行をいっそ全て改行のままにしてしまう方式も直感的で良いのかもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

代案とデメリットを挙げます。

### 代案

#### <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd>や<kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>で空白を2つ末尾に入れた改行を入れられるようにする

WordやPagesなどのWYSIWYGエディタやスプレッドシートなど、改行キーが純粋な改行と紐付けられていないアプリケーションでは <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd>や<kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>で改行を入れられるようになっています。このキーバインディングを実装すれば、Markdownの改行記法に慣れていなくても自然に編集ができるのではないかと思います。

意図的に改行を入れなければいけないというハードルは残るので、後で挙げる「読みにくい投稿が増える」デメリットもそんなにないのではないかと期待します。

#### 全角の空白2つを強制改行とみなすようにする

おそらく大体のIMEはShift+スペースキーで半角の空白を入力できると思います。もし全角の空白を誤って入力しがち、ということであれば、全角の空白2つを強制改行とみなすようにしてもよいと思います。

関連ソースコード: [Markdown.cs](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/browse/MarkdownSharp/Markdown.cs#1422)

### 改行をそのまま改行として扱うことのデメリット

#### 掲示板のような「おしゃべり」を歓迎するサイトのように見える

- 日本語は英語に比べて改行が多い
- 日本語で一般的な作文スタイルは改行を推奨するものではない

どちらも個人的に賛成です。

ただ、前者は但し書き付きです: 改行が多いのは、掲示板やメールなどにおける、話し言葉に近いコミュニケーションの場です。ウェブ上の文献や読み物においては、段落中の改行はほとんどないといっていいと思います。掲示板やメールなどの古くからあるシステムでは一定文字数で改行するのがマナーだったという歴史があるが、最近のウェブサイトのコンテンツは改行を使わないスタイルが主流になっている、ということもできます。(根拠: [Wikipediaの編集ガイド](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86#.E6.AE.B5.E8.90.BD.E3.83.BB.E6.94.B9.E8.A1.8C))

例として、[「ほぼ日」](http://www.1101.com/home.html)は文節単位で改行を入れるスタイルですが、これは話し言葉のような伝え方をしたいがために意図的に確立させたスタイルだそうです ([「インターネット的」より](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=xh0wBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT83&ots=2Ods1fkp9g&dq=%E3%81%BB%E3%81%BC%E6%97%A5%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%20%E6%94%B9%E8%A1%8C&pg=PT83#v=onepage&q=%E3%81%BB%E3%81%BC%E6%97%A5%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%20%E6%94%B9%E8%A1%8C&f=false))。

Stack Overflowはその場限りのQ&Aではなく、将来的にも参照しやすいリソースとしての性格が強いと個人的に思っているので、段落中の改行はほとんど無いスタイルの方がしっくりきます。

極論すると、改行を積極的に歓迎する変更は、掲示板サイトに方向転換をするのと同じではないかと思います。

#### 読みにくい投稿が増え、読者の自由度が減る

まず例をいくつか:

[image: 4686]

[image: 4826]

[image: 4944]

改行の扱いの変更以降、段落中で改行している投稿が増えています。根拠: [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)で投稿データを取得して分析した結果、投稿のHTML本文に`<br>`タグが1つ以上ある投稿は14%から51%に増えていました。(Markdown上で、段落中に改行がある投稿の割合は約50%でほぼ変わっていません。)

個人的には、これは行の長さが不揃いで読みにくいですし、モバイル版ではさらに不揃いになって読みにくいです。任意の環境で快適に読めない、というのは読者として自由度が低いサイトです。

また、Markdownのかわりに改行によって整形している投稿も増えています。

質問中で「リストを作成したい場合」に改行を使う、とありますが、これは読みにくい改行の使い方です。投稿者によってまちまちな整形の仕方のリストより、Markdownのリスト記法による統一的な見た目を期待できる方が読解の労力が少なくて済みます。

例:

[image: 4931]

読みにくい投稿は編集で改善できるのはもちろんですが、読みにくいコンテンツを投稿しやすくする必要はない、ということもできます。

Comment: 改行の課題からはじめ、現在２つの問題について話していると思います。①は投稿の質です。②は改行の入力方法です。入力方法としてこれはいい代案と思いますが、適用しても事例として出している質問が消えないと想定します。事例の問題点は改行のみではなく、書式がわからないのもあるし、質問の聞き方自体に慣れていないと見えます。質の面では将来に向けて、このような改行を入れすぎると自動的に[低湿な投稿レビュー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)に入るべきだと思います。書式の適用方法は質にあまり影響がないと思いますが、書式の方法により、底質が把握しやすくなる可能性はあります。

Comment: @jmac たしかに問題は2つあります。そして、改行の入力方法が書式の問題に影響を与えていると思います。現状では改行でMarkdownの代用ができてしまうので、Markdownを覚える機会を失うこともあるかもしれません。入力作業のしやすさだけでなく、その後の編集作業の負荷や、サイト全体の印象や方向性も含めた判断が必要であると思います。レビューに入れるのはシステマチックでよいですね。