# スポイラーの中にHTMLタグを書くと空行が挿入されてしまう

Tags: バグ, 仕様, markdown

[スポイラー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/19110)の中に HTML のブロック要素を書くと、謎の空行 `<br>` が行間に挿入されてしまうバグを見つけました。

Markdown:

```
>!<pre><code>int main() {
>!    printf("Hello, world!\n");
>!    return 0;
>!}</code></pre>
```

> ```
> int main() {
>
>     printf("Hello, world!\n");
>
>     return 0;
>
> }
> ```

期待した HTML (expected result):

```html
<blockquote class="spoiler">
  <p><pre><code>int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}</code></pre></p>
</blockquote>
```

実際の HTML (actual result):

```html
<blockquote class="spoiler">
  <p><pre><code>int main() {<br>
    printf("Hello, world!\n");<br>
    return 0;<br>
}</code></pre></p>
</blockquote>
```

Meta Stack Exchange や英語版 Stack Overflow ではこの空行が生成されませんでした。生成されない方が正常だと思うので、直して頂きたいです。

- 関連バグ?? (related bug??): https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1686/19110
- もしかして: [Markdown の処理が](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1587/19110) [他サイトと異なる](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1513/19110)ため生まれたバグ？

---

To SE Team: It seems that HTML block tags in a spoiler are not correctly rendered as on SO or MSE. Perhaps this is because raw newlines are [treated](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1587/19110) [differently](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1513/19110) on SOja.

Comment: リクエストいたしました m_ _m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ここでの問題はスポイラーがMarkdown構文においてStack Exchange固有の拡張であるため他の形式のマークアップとはうまく動作しないことです。この場合、コードフォーマットではうまく動作しません。動作するのであればブロック引用のスポイラーのようにコードスポイラーを書くことができます。

通常であれば :

```
>     int main() {
>         printf("Hello, world!\n");
>         return 0;
>     }
```

...このように :

> ```
> int main() {
>     printf("Hello, world!\n");
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

しかし動作しないので :

```
>!     int main() {
>!         printf("Hello, world!\n");
>!         return 0;
>!     }
```

...結果はコードとしてフォーマットされません。このため、[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105735/how-can-i-put-a-whole-code-block-in-spoiler-text)では、HTMLを使用してコードをフォーマットすることが推奨されています。しかし、スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版サイトでは改行を `<br>` と用いているため、ここではそれがうまくいきません。

適切な解決方法（どこでも使用可能なもの）は、スポイラープロセッサーをトリックし、
スポイラー段落内の各行の先頭に感嘆符（！）を挿入して通常のブロック引用をスポイラーとして扱うことです。

こちらのHTMLだと :

```
<blockquote><p>
!<pre><code>int main() {
!    printf("Hello, world!\n");
!    return 0;
!}</code></pre>
</p></blockquote>
```

このように :

> ```
> int main() {
>     printf("Hello, world!\n");
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

これを効果的に使用するにはHTMLマークアップ解析を妨げてくれるコードを手動でエスケープする必要があります。例）`&` は `&amp;`、 `<` は `&lt;`、等