# ```で囲む形式のコードブロックが実装され（て）ました

Tags: サポート, markdown

Stack Exchange では、長らく行頭にスペース 4 つ入れる形式のコードブロックだけが実装されており、いわゆる「コードフェンス」形式のコードブロックは実装されていませんでした。

ところが、2019 年 1 月頃から[コードフェンスが使えるようになった](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/341401)みたいです！　つまり、たとえばバックティック 3 つでテキストを囲むと、

````
```
このように囲むと……
```
````

↓

```
コードブロックとして表示されます！
```

### 正確な文法

[balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) による[この投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/341401)によると、以下のように [CommonMark 0.28](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#fenced-code-blocks) 準拠のものが使えます。

> - コードフェンスは 3 個以上のバックティック ```` ``` ```` かチルダ `~~~` から成り、0～3 個のスペースでインデントできます。
> - コードを挟む 2 つのコードフェンスのうち上側のものには[シンタックスハイライトの指示](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)を後ろに書けます。Stack Exchange 上では、Prettify のモジュール名 (例: ```` ```lang-cxx ````) か、シンタックスハイライトの設定がなされたタグ名 (例: ```` ```lang-c++ ````) が書けます。```` ```none ```` と書くとハイライトが抑制されます。
> - 下側のコードフェンスは上側のものと同じ記号を使わなければいけません。また、少なくとも上側のものと同じ数だけ記号が連続していないといけません。
> - コードブロックの中身は、上側のコードフェンスがインデントされているスペースの数だけインデントが無視されます。したがって下のように書くと、
>
>   ````
>   このブロックです:
>     ```
>     hoge
>       fuga
>     ```
>   ````
>
>   こうなります。
>
>   > このブロックです:
>   >
>   > ```
>   > hoge
>   >   fuga
>   > ```
> - 下側で閉じられていないコードブロックは、ブロック要素 (例: 引用ブロック) が終わるまでか、投稿が終わるまで有効になります。

### お願い

この文法はいつの間にか日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでも使えるようになっていました。そこでお願いなのですが、この変更によって何か変なことが起こっていれば知りたいです。

1. もしこの変更によって表示が崩れている投稿があれば、編集して直してください。たとえばチルダを使った水平線 `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~` を使っていると変になることがあるかもしれません。
2. もしコードフェンスを使ったコードブロックが上手く動かないことがあれば、バグとしてメタ投稿してください。特に日本語版スタック・オーバーフローは [改行まわりに](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1587/19110) [特殊な処理が入っている](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1513/19110) ので、表示が変になる場合がないか気になっています。

なお、この変更は投稿が新しく編集されない限り反映されず、表示はそのままになるそうです。よって既存の投稿がおかしくなるとすれば編集後です。

それにしても、個人的にずっと「コードフェンス使えないのかな～」と思っていたので、この変更はとっても嬉しいです！　これで混乱が更に減りました :)