# コード記法のデフォルトをbacktickを使うものにして欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, markdown

現在のスタック・オーバーフローにはコードブロック用の記法が[ふたつあります](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2952/19110)。

ひとつは行頭にスペースを入れるもの。

```
    puts "Hello!"
```

もうひとつは backtick で囲うもの (fenced code block) です。

````
```
puts "Hello!"
```
````

質問を投稿する際のエディタで `{}` ボタンを押したり Ctrl-K を押したりするとコード記法を挿入することができます。現在、コードブロック用の記法のデフォルトは、スペースを入れるものが使われています。

これを backtick で囲うものに変えたいです。以下の理由から backtick の方が便利だと考えています。

- 個人的に普段 Markdown として良く書くのは backtick 方式で、こちらの方が馴染みがあります。
- backtick 方式だと余計なインデントが増えないので Python などインデントが重要となってくる言語のプログラムをコードブロックにする際、変に悩まなくて良くなります。
- 初心者の方でも構文が分かりやすいです。「1 行目だけコードブロックで、2 行目から普通のテキスト」なんて状況を自然に回避できます。
- シンタックスハイライト用の記法も backtick の方が簡潔です。
- コードブロックがふたつ連続する際に奇妙なワークアラウンドをとらなくても良くなります（スペース方式の場合、[language comment](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2708/19110) を間に挟むと合併を防げるって、ご存知でした？）

Comment: backtick を使用したコードブロックをブロック引用化しようとすると一行にまとめられてしまう (というより、 backtick の位置が変なところに移動する？) ので、それが解決すれば nekketsuuu さんの意見に賛成です。

Answer (score 3):

最近になって MSE 全体で Markdown のレンダリングが **CommonMark** という形式に変更されました。(既にスタック・オーバーフローに対しても適用済みのようです)

[We're switching to CommonMark - MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746)

この変更に合わせて、編集時のツールバーでのコードハイライトをコードフェンスに変えて欲しいと [要望を出してみました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349575) 。